# Етимологія слова "габілійчик"

Tags: етимологія

Цікавить етимологія слова "габілійчик" (претендент на певну наукову посаду або наукове звання), яке я зустрів у [словнику](https://zbruc.eu/node/26095) з творів Івана Франка. Пошук в [Етимологічному словнику](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1982/EtSlUkrM_1982.pdf) не дав ніяких результатів, в Гуглі також не вдалося знайти ніякої інформації, а крім того цього слова немає в СУМі.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Анґлійська Вікі](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation) тут дуже зручна, по-1, наводить давнину і словопохоџення:

> The term **habilitation** is derived from the Medieval Latin *habilitare*, meaning “to make suitable, to fit”, from Classical Latin [*habilis*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/habilis) “fit, proper, skillful”. The degree developed in Germany in the seventeenth century (c. 1652). Initially, habilitation was synonymous with **doctoral qualification**. The term became synonymous with **post-doctoral qualification** in Germany in the 19th century “when holding a doctorate seemed no longer sufficient to guarantee a proficient transfer of knowledge to the next generation”. Afterwards, it became normal in the German university system to write two doctoral theses: the inaugural thesis (*Inauguraldissertation*), completing a course of study; and the habilitation thesis (*Habilitationsschrift*), which opens the road to a professorship.

Тобто слово Латіньського [похоџення](//etymonline.com/word/habilitate) зі значіням *здатність*, але підлаштований Німцями, котрого, як далї бачно, підхопили Поляки і не тільки.

А, по-2, це перелік йменювань в мовах, ось потрібне:

> [Poland](//wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=32882&id_znaczenia=3849496) (dr hab., doktor habilitowany)

Правда, знайшов лиш [habilitant](//sjp.pl/habilitant)·[ka](//sjp.pl/habilitantka). Xoча знаю, що наростка *чик* Польська теж має без змін як [*czyk*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-czyk), але не знахоџу. Тому це може бути таким собі украӥньським новотворем, можливо й Франком. Правда, я не знаю яким чином тут *й* знаходиться за словотвореням.

Answer (score 4):

Слово "габілійчик" було утворене від слова [*"габілітація"*](https://zbruc.eu/node/26095), що також наявне у словнику з творів Івана Франка одразу після слова "габілійчик":

> габілітація
>
> Габіліта́ція:
>
> — доведення права на самостійну діяльність в галузі науки та викладання в університеті [39]
>
> — захист наукової роботи на право читання лекцій в університеті [27;41;49]
>      — захист наукової роботи, що дає право читати лекції в університеті [31]
>
> — іспит на право викладання в університеті [29]
>
> — складання іспиту на право викладати в університеті [46-2]

Слово *"habilitation"* в свою чергу наявне в більшості мов германської мовної групи: в [англійській](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/habilitation), [німецькій](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Habilitation), [французькій](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/habilitation/38759). *"Habilitation"* походить від латинського слова [*"habilis"*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=habilis) - "зручний, вмілий". Прикметник *"habilis"* походить від дієслова [*"habeo"*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=habeo&la=la&can=habeo0) - мати, тримати, носити, одягати, підтримувати. Коріння цього слова походять ще з праіндоєвропейської мови: від [*"ghabh"*](https://indo-european.info/pokorny-etymological-dictionary/whnjs.htm), що ймовірно мало значення ["брати", "отримувати"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=ghabh-).

Отже найвірогідніше, що слово "габілійчик" у своєму значенні було запозичине з якоїсь мови з-поміж германської мовної групи (швидше за все з німецької) через польську.